# Analytics showing many 0 second visits

Tags: experience-analytics

We are seeing numerous 0 second visits in Experience Analytics, some even with an API call URL and no page URL.

How can we troubleshoot this to determine if these should be tracked or if there is an error in the tracking or robot detection or some other issue?

Some of these 0 second visits occur in a pattern throughout the calendar months.

Thank you in advance =)

[image]

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: We are running Sitecore XP 9.0.2 Thank you!

Comment: @NotAnotherCliche: Please click on the link under the 'Name' heading and see the stats on the bottom of the page on the right side. Also, are you using EXM?

Comment: Hi @NutsAndBolts, we are using EXM, yes. And the individual stats/drilldown for each of the users showing in the table above shows 0 seconds and matches the data shown above.

Any idea what would cause 0 second visits, especially so many? The snapshot above is an accurate representation of most of our data, e.g. more 0 second visits than not.

Comment: @NotAnotherCliche I'm also seeing this issue on one of my sites. Did you figure out the root cause?